# How to compare fields between arrays of objects?

Tags: java, android, arrays, compare

I have two arrays of objects:
`ArrayList<Object> list1` и `ArrayList<Object> list2`.

Example of my code (simplified):

```
Class Object1 {
String str1 = "example";
}

Class Object2 {
String str2 = "example";
}

ArrayList<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(new Object1());
ArrayList<Object> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add(new Object2());
```

Problem: I need to compare fields str1 and str2 (between Object1 and Object2 that location in a different arrays)

Comment: let `Object1` and `Object2` implement the same Interface which declares a getter method in which each class returns its string. Then let both classes implement `Comparable`  interface in which each class compares its string with the return value of the common interfaces getter method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Compare Two List's object values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207718/java-compare-two-lists-object-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason why you can't iterate through 1 list, call the getter for the field and compare it with the corresponding object in the other list?

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
    Object obj1 = list1.get(i);
    Object obj2 = list2.get(i);
    System.out.println(obj1.str1.equals(obj2.str2)); // Better use getter here instead
}
```

Comment: In this case, I do not have access to getters. What can be wrong? (This code is used in the method not being "main")

Comment: @GlebTserr Technically, nothing. But design-wise, it's bad practice and should be avoided as it breaks encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

you can compare list1.get(0).str1 with list2.get(0).str2. In case you are using a  for loop, in place of get(0), use get(i).

Comment: In this case, I do not have access to the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare `str1` and `str2` like

```
list1.get(indexOfObject1InList1).str1.equals(list2.get(indexOfObject2InList2).str2)
```

Comment: I do not have access via the operator "point" to the variables. What can be wrong?