# How do we compare String Array value to a String? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, comparison

I was wondering if I could compare the String Array value to a String, for eg; I have a String array which has 5 values on it. `String [] sampleArray = {"a","b","a","b","a"}` and I want to know which index value has `a` or `b`. I thought of an idea but it didn't work.

```
String[] sampleArray = {"a","b","a","b","a"};
String value;
for (int i=0; i <= sampleArray.length; i++){
  if ( sampleArray[i].equals("a") ) {
    value = "apple";
  } else {
    value = "ball";
  }
  System.out.println(value);
}
```

Basically if the `index 0` is `a` then it should print "Apple" and if it's `b` it should print "ball" and so on. Is there any idea to compare values or string array to a string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Compare Two List's object values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207718/java-compare-two-lists-object-values)

Comment: *"I have a `String` array which has 5 values on it. `String [] sampleArray = {"a","b","a","b","a"}` and I want to know if my first index value is whether a or b."* if (sampleArray[0].equals("a"))` does that. What's the loop for?

Comment: It didn't work -> maybe you mean the *"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5"*?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, that was my mistake in questioning part. I wanted to know which index has which value and know whether or not that "if statement" is valid. I edited the question.

Comment: What kind of output do you want? your sample does not match with your question

Comment: @Romain If the index 0 in the array is "a" it should print "apple" and if it's "b" it should print "ball" and so on.

Comment: @सृजनसृजन Your code is already doing the job. All you need to fix is the conditional statement in the for cycle definition: *i < sampleArray.length*;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get your question, you are trying to see if `sampleArray[0]` is equal to "a".

Your code does compare the first index of your array but does not keep the result of your comparaison.

The reason is that your variable `value` change each loop. In the end, I suppose you are getting this in the console :

```
apple
```

But this value of your `value` variable is the result of the comparaison of the last index, `sampleArray[4]` and "a".
In your code, the value of `value` is erase at each loop by the next comparaison, at the end you only get the value of the last one.

If you want to get a result like

```
apple
ball
apple
ball
apple
```

You need to print the result at each loop just like this :

```
for (int i=0; i < sampleArray.length; i++){
     if ( sampleArray[i].equals("a") ) {
        System.out.println("apple");
     } else {
        System.out.println("ball");
     }
}
```

**Be careful here**, `sampleArray.length` is equal to five, but index in most programming languages are going from **0 to length-1**.
So `i <= sampleArray.length` will probably throw a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

I hope it answers your question.